# Input from keyboard in assembly language using system call

Tags: macos, assembly, input, x86, nasm

I am trying to create my own gets and puts function using system calls in NASM assembly language. So far the puts function works in this code just fine but I can not get the terminal to wait for input from the keyboard in the gets function.

```
global start

SECTION .text

SECTION .data
    prompt1: db "We will make you a box.  How tall would you like it to be?", 0
    length1: equ $-prompt1
    prompt2: db "How wide would you like it to be?" , 0
    length2: equ $-prompt2
    input: dd 0




start:
    mov edi, prompt1
    mov esi, length1
    call puts

    mov edi, input
    mov esi, 4
    call gets

    mov eax, 0
    ret


puts:
    mov dword [esp], 1
    mov dword [esp+8], esi
    mov dword [esp+4], edi
    mov eax, 0x4
    sub esp, 4
    int 0x80
    add esp, 16
    ret

gets:
    mov dword [esp], 0
    mov dword [esp+4], esi
    mov dword [esp+8], edi
    mov eax, 3
    sub esp, 4
    int 0x80
    add esp, 16
    ret
```

This is the output:
    We will make you a box.  How tall would you like it to be?

But it doesn't prompt for input... Help please!

Comment: First You must search:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787891/linux-x86-asm-getting-user-input

Comment: After a `call`, `[esp]` holds your return address... or did, before you clobbered it. If you're going to use the stack like that, `sub esp, 12` first.

Comment: @icbytes forgot to specify mac os x...

Comment: @FrankKotler you actually don't have to sub from the stack first.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I need to use the .bss section for uninitialized data.